# SQL ORACLE converting columns into rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, unpivot

I have the result with the columns Indice,valeur1 etc:

Indice value1   value2 value3   value4

1        x        maths  physics  chemistry

2      21/01/18   133    184       115

I would like to display the result in a vertical manner like

```
Indice,1,2
valeur1, x,21/01/2018
valeur2,maths, 133
valeur3,physics,184
valeur4,chemistry ,115
...
...
...
...
```

My query:

```
    select
    'x' as Valeur1,
    'maths' as Valeur2,
    'physics' as Valeur3, 
    'Chemistry' as Valeur4, 
    null as Valeur5, 
    null as Valeur6, 
    null as Valeur7, 
    null as Valeur8, 
    null as Valeur9, 
    null as Valeur10 
    from dual
    union
    select
        2 as indice,
      to_char((x) ) as Valeur1,
      to_char(sum(maths)) as valeur2,
      to_char(sum(physics)) as valeur3,
      to_char(sum(chemisty)) as valeur4,
      null as Valeur5, 
      null as Valeur6, 
      null as Valeur7, 
      null as Valeur8, 
      null as Valeur9, 
      null as Valeur10 

 from t1
```

I would like to transpose the columns into rows in the result.
Could you please suggest me the possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You need [`UNPIVOT`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1).

```
select * from unpivotdemo;

    INDICE VALEUR1              VALEUR2              VALEUR3              VALEUR4              VALEUR5              VALEUR6              VALEUR7              VALEUR8              VALEUR9              VALEUR10
---------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 Semaine courante     Semaine precedente   Semaine -2                                                                                                                                         
         2 03/10/18             184                  115                                                                                                                                                

select indice, valeur, description
from   unpivotdemo
unpivot
     ( description for valeur in
       ( valeur1
       , valeur2
       , valeur3
       , valeur4
       , valeur5
       , valeur6
       , valeur7
       , valeur8
       , valeur9
       , valeur10 ) );

    INDICE VALEUR   DESCRIPTION
---------- -------- --------------------
         1 VALEUR1  Semaine courante
         1 VALEUR2  Semaine precedente
         1 VALEUR3  Semaine -2
         2 VALEUR1  03/10/18
         2 VALEUR2  184
         2 VALEUR3  115

6 rows selected
```

By default null values are excluded. You can include them by adding `include nulls` after the `unpivot` keyword.

To include `INDICE` in the `VALEUR` column, you can move it from the `select` list to the `unpivot ... in` list - however you also need to convert the datatype to match:

```
select valeur, description
from   ( select to_char(indice) as indice
               , valeur1, valeur2, valeur3, valeur4, valeur5, valeur6, valeur7, valeur8, valeur9, valeur10
         from   unpivotdemo d )
unpivot include nulls
     ( description for valeur in
       ( indice
       , valeur1
       , valeur2
       , valeur3
       , valeur4
       , valeur5
       , valeur6
       , valeur7
       , valeur8
       , valeur9
       , valeur10 ) );

VALEUR   DESCRIPTION
-------- ----------------------------------------
INDICE   1
VALEUR1  Semaine courante
VALEUR2  Semaine precedente
VALEUR3  Semaine -2
VALEUR4  
VALEUR5  
VALEUR6  
VALEUR7  
VALEUR8  
VALEUR9  
VALEUR10 
INDICE   2
VALEUR1  03/10/18
VALEUR2  184
VALEUR3  115
VALEUR4  
VALEUR5  
VALEUR6  
VALEUR7  
VALEUR8  
VALEUR9  
VALEUR10 

22 rows selected
```

Edit following expanded question:

To aggregate the values into comma-separated strings, you can use [`LISTAGG`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/listagg-function-enhancements-12cr2):

```
select valeur, description
from   ( select listagg(indice, ',')   within group (order by indice) as indice
              , listagg(valeur1, ',')  within group (order by indice) as valeur1
              , listagg(valeur2, ',')  within group (order by indice) as valeur2
              , listagg(valeur3, ',')  within group (order by indice) as valeur3
              , listagg(valeur4, ',')  within group (order by indice) as valeur4
              , listagg(valeur5, ',')  within group (order by indice) as valeur5
              , listagg(valeur6, ',')  within group (order by indice) as valeur6
              , listagg(valeur7, ',')  within group (order by indice) as valeur7
              , listagg(valeur8, ',')  within group (order by indice) as valeur8
              , listagg(valeur9, ',')  within group (order by indice) as valeur9
              , listagg(valeur10, ',') within group (order by indice) as valeur10
         from   unpivotdemo )
unpivot include nulls
     ( description for valeur in
       ( indice
       , valeur1
       , valeur2
       , valeur3
       , valeur4
       , valeur5
       , valeur6
       , valeur7
       , valeur8
       , valeur9
       , valeur10 ) );

VALEUR   DESCRIPTION
-------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INDICE   1,2
VALEUR1  Semaine courante,03/10/18
VALEUR2  Semaine precedente,184
VALEUR3  Semaine -2,115
VALEUR4  
VALEUR5  
VALEUR6  
VALEUR7  
VALEUR8  
VALEUR9  
VALEUR10 

11 rows selected
```

Note that the comma-separated strings could get long, and by default you are limited to 4000 characters which might be about 200 rows based on your sample data.

Comment: Thanks William Roberston for your help.I am trying to adapt your query with mine.But I couldn't succeed  yet .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like

```
select * from (
    select indice from table union all
    select value1 from table union all
    select value2....union all
    select last from table
)
```

Or else make use of `unpivot` as

```
select column from table
unpivot ( column for column in (indice, value1, ... valuen) )
```